# Is it possible to check if livestream is streaming?

Tags: php, ajax, live-streaming

i have a website with multiple streams and want to promote the ones that are currently streaming.

the only solution i've found was something with an hidden flash player, WICH I DO NOT WANT (flash is great but not everywhere and i fear about it draining my bandwith)

what's the most efficient way to check a livestream?

Feeds can be MMS or HTTP

Answer (score 2):

This highly depends on the service. For quick reference, I've included examples to some popular streaming sites:

- own3d.tv: [http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=**[stream id]**](http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=%5bstreamid%5d)
- [justin.tv/twitch.tv](http://www.justin.tv/p/api): [http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.xml?channel=**[channel]**](http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.xml?channel=%5bchannel%5d)
- [livestream.com](http://www.livestream.com/userguide/index.php?title=Channel_API#Channel_Live_Status): [http://x**[channel]**x.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.xml](http://x%5bchannel%5dx.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.xml)

**Requires API key:**

- [ustream.tv](http://developer.ustream.tv/data_api/docs): [http://api.ustream.tv/php/channel/**[channel]**/getValueOf/status?key=**[your API key]**](http://api.ustream.tv/php/channel/%5bchannel%5d/getValueOf/status?key=%5byour-API-key%5d)

By polling these, you can see if they are online. I recommend you check out the terms for each of the APIs before using them tho.

I'm sure some, or maybe even most of these support JSON aswell.

Comment: i like your answer but i'm looking for something on my own server - we do not use external streaming service. (will check code references and see if it fit before validating)

Comment: If you are in control of the service, shouldn't you somehow have that information available? If a stream is live, I mean...?

Comment: i wish it was that easy, it's our server but i have no access to it. we currently have a system working by manually entered dates but i wanted to make it "automatic"

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to somehow poll the stream itself. I don't have alot of experience with this, but I found this question on SO semi-relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778195/check-if-mms-stream-exists-or-not-using-php - Hopefully it will be of help.